# Replace Value with value from another Column in SQL

Tags: sql, replace

In SQL I have 2 columns, `ReportedDate` (`DATETIME`) and `ReportedTime` (`char(5)`) with the `ReportedDate` column always showing 0s for the times, ex. '2022-10-04 00:00:00.000'.

I need to combine the `ReportedDate` and `ReportedTime` values from the same row to be displayed in a new column.

The result needs to be of `DATETIME` data type.

For example:

- ReportedDate: '2022-10-04 00:00:00.000'
- ReportedTime: '10:17'
- Desired end result: '2022-10-04 10:17:00.000'

When I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(ReportedDate, '00:00:00', CONVERT(time, ReportedTime))) AS StartTime
FROM EventDate
```

My end result returned `ReportedDate` with no changes made to it in the new `StartTime` column, which I suspect is happening because the `REPLACE` function isn't able to read the `ReportedTime` value because its not in quotes.

Comment: you need to 1) tag question with DBMS, 2) show table DLL,  Why would you be storing a separate column for time when DATETIME type has a time component?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to concatenate these two columns

**Update**:
Based on edit the question is more clear.

> ReportedDate format : '2022-10-04 00:00:00.000'
>
> ReportedTime format: '10:17'
>
> Desired end result: '2022-10-04 10:17:00.000'

This can be achieved as follows :

```
select
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, ReportedDate, 23), ' ', ReportedTime)) AS StartTime
from EventDate
```

Here is a more reference for :
[How to get different date formats in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)

Comment: From the CONVERT() I guess that this question is about SQL Server.
The issue of adding dates and times is handled in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51440/how-to-combine-date-and-time-to-datetime2-in-sql-server